# problem animating appearing text

Tags: rendering

Making a logo - very simple - 5 words all set on a black background that appear independently in sequence.  I used the Outliner editor to set keyframes for the text to appear.  It works as designed in the render view but when I animate the logo all of the words are visible at frame 1.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Need more details. What property are you applying the keyframes to? What do you mean by "the render view" and "when I animate"? There are known issues with keyframing OpenGL opacity due to shader caching and that may be what you're encountering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Blender, there are always two Settings for Viewport and Rendering. For Viewport visibility use [image: visible_ipo_on] and for Rendering [image: restrict_render_off]